# Outlook 2010 calendar showing appointment without accepting anything

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

One of the users in my office just emailed me asking why there was a calendar entry without her accepting any requests. The request came from outside the business.

Am I right in thinking that when a calendar request is sent it automatically shows up in the calendar, and then stays or disappears dependent on whether or not you accept it?

OK just tried this with a co-worker and yes, it does display a placeholder appointment before you accept or decline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have settings on your Email account calendar known as tentative so you can set the users calendar to place a tentative placeholder for acceptance or rejection.

If you go to File > Options > Mail > Sroll down Tracking > tick/un-tick 'Automatically process meeting requests and responses to meeting requests and polls'

This should allow you to change the behavior although more control can be had by changing this backend not via Outlook, any Exchange IT engineer should be able to change these backend..